# Problems when using validator inside a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, validation

When I use f:validator inside a field of a dataTable, doesn't work, if I insert a breakpoint in my validator class, it never executes.

My dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{contrato.plantillaPrograma}" var="pl" scrollHeight="300" rendered="#{contrato.abrirPrograma}" autoUpdate="true">
    <p:column headerText="#{txtMsg['crearContrato.fecha']}" style="width:125px"
    sortBy="#{pl.fecha}">
        <h:inputText value="#{pl.fecha}">
            <f:converter converterId="dateConverter" />
        </h:inputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{txtMsg['crearContrato.programa']}" style="width:125px"
    sortBy="#{pl.programa}">
        <h:inputText value="#{pl.programa}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{txtMsg['crearContrato.fechaFactura']}" style="width:125px"
    sortBy="#{pl.fechaFactura}">
        <p:inputText value="#{pl.fechaFactura}" validator="sheetEnFirme">
            <f:converter converterId="dateConverter"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My class:
    package es.axpo.jsf.validator;

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator(value="sheetEnFirme")
public class SheetEnFirmeValidator implements Validator{
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent comp, Object obj)
            throws ValidatorException {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Error"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use `f:validator` in the given code but the `validator` attribute (which normally should be the same). But did you try it with `f:validator` at all?

Comment: Yes, first of all, I used f:validator tag.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `#{contrato}` bean is at least `@ViewScoped`. Make sure that you aren't preparing `plantillaPrograma` in its getter method, but instead in bean's (post)constructor. Make sure that the `dateConverter` hasn't thrown a `ConverterException` which you should have noticed by a faces message in `<h:message(s)>` or in the server's log.

By the way, why are you not just using the builtin `<f:convertDateTime>` for dates?

Comment: Hello, the bean is viewScoped, and plantillaPrograma is generated in a fileUpload method (Uploading an excel file I generate the table), dateConverter hasn't thrown any exception, I checked server logs, an there is nothing wrong. I'm using sutom converter because when I started making the architecture of the app, I defined some converters, maybe ignoring that there was already implemented, but the converter works fine, the problem is on validator. I don't know why, but this only happens when I use inside a dataTable, in other views, works fine. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.

My problem was on the command button, I had property process="@this", when removed, validation works fine